# SharePoint 2013 - How to reorder apps in Site Contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Our Site Contents page is beginning to grow with many apps.  Is there an easy way to re-arrange, or reorder the most  important apps towards the top, and the least important apps towards the bottom, this way non-technical users don't have to continuously search for the right app to click on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a better idea to show the important apps in the left menu, so the user finds the popular apps that way. It also saves the user a click since the user does not have to go through Site Contents.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that we can use the "Promoted Links" app as a tool to add links to a page, which appear as thumbnail items, and can be re-ordered.  This is exactly what I need.

Comment: do you have more details on this? e.g. how you did it?